# Can't copy files with 'additional permissions' to ext4 drive -- files that have @ after permissions, like -rwxrwxrwx@

Tags: linux, networking, filesystems, samba

I am copying files from Snow Leopard to a mounted ext4 share via Samba, that's on a Fedora machine. Some files cannot be copied, and give this error:

> The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have permission to access some of the items.

I've noticed that the files that can't be copied have an @ at the end of their permissions whien I do 'ls -l' in the command line. For example, I can copy the second file but not the first:

```
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 miles  staff     1448 May 14 22:55 test.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 miles  staff     136 Apr  5 17:06 image.psd.zip
```

From what I've found, the @ means the file has 'additional properties'. Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue so I can copy the files to the fileshare??

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** It sounds like i need to mount the ext4 drive using 'user_xattr' (see mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/…). But I haven't figured out how to do that. I see where it's mounted, in /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/fedora-raid/FedoraRaid  /media/share  ext4  defaults  1 2
```

I changed it to:

```
/dev/fedora-raid/FedoraRaid  /media/share  ext4  defaults, user_attr,acl  1 2
```

but then the share didn't mount at all

How do I make that use 'user_attr'?

Comment: The `fstab` entry you list here has a space after `defaults,`. That could definitely cause some trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem ("useradd" copies skel files from 
root (ext3) to home (ext4) partition with this error).

Mounting ext4 with option "acl" solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't need these extended attributes.

Try to use cp [without copying the extended attributes](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html#index-file-information_002c-preserving-891).

> cp --no-preserve=xattr source
>
> Do not preserve the specified
>   attributes. The attribute_list has the
>   same form as for --preserve.

Or mount with `nouser_xattr` option editing your fstab (backup your original /etc/fstab file). Check [it's structure](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html#over) to avoid problems. If needed, check `fstab` man page for more information.

```
/dev/fedora-raid/FedoraRaid /media/share ext4 defaults,nouser_xattr 1 2
```

Beware of spaces in fstab, the options in this file are separated by spaces, so if you use one in your fourth column for example is not going to work. If your directory does have a space in it, [use this solution](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/2287-fstab-adding-spaces-in-the-mount-point-path).

Comment: I'll try it, but I don't want to be restricted to only copying files from the command-line. See my 'update' in the original post.

Comment: Both solutions (cp in cmd and mount)? Unfortunately I don't have a setup like yours to help in your problem...

Comment: In Finder I got the same error as before. On command line with your suggestion I got cp -no-preserve=xattr /screenshot.jpg  /Volumes/share/files/
cp: illegal option -- o
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory

Comment: I setup VSFTP and I can copy the files over through that. So, that's a reasonable workaround, but I'd still love to be able to copy via Finder.